# Abstract Object Comparison in Java

Tags: java, object, abstract-class, comparable

I am implementing a heap for abstract objects.
Now I was able to implement a stack as there are no comparisons required for a Stack.
However the heap requires comparisons.
So I have `Object A`, and `Object B`. I can ensure that the `Object` that are in the `heap` are of the same class, and that they can be ordered (that is the class has a `compareTo` function to know `if A<B, A=B, or A>B)`.
But if I use `A.compareTo(B)`, I get a syntax error saying that `compareTo` is not defined for objects.
I did some research and found that Object does not implement Comparable.
How can I go about this problem.
Thank you.

Comment: Implement the Comparable interface, of course.

Comment: I have implemented the comparable interface. But the Object as such does not implement Comparable interface.

Comment: Did you write `implements Comparable` after `public class ClassName`? Just including a `compareTo` method will not make it a Comparable.

Comment: Then I'd recommend a Stack<Comparable> or Heap<Comparable> instead of Object.

Comment: [Comparation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) can be implemented using `Comparator` class, not `Comparable` interface. Maybe this will be helpfull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if all your objects were descendants of a common ancestor which do implement `Comparable`? So in that case you could use that type in your code not `Object`.

Answer (score 1):

Object does not implements comparable. You should crate MyObject which implements `Comparable` interface.

```
class MyObject implements Comparable<Object>{
    ...
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object arg0) {
        //  custom logic
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**-** Well you can make that class implement `java.lang.Comparable` Interface with `Object` as **Type Parameter**

```
public class Test implements Comparable<Object>{

    public int compareTo(Object o){

       // 

    }

}
```